# insertion sort on linked list

Tags: doubly-linked-list, insertion-sort

//I wrote java code for insertion method on doubly linked list but there is a infinite loop //when I run it. I'm trying to find a bug, but have not found so far. any suggestions? 
//it is calling a helper function

```
 public IntList insertionSort ( ) {
    DListNode soFar = null;
    for (DListNode p=myHead; p!=null; p=p.myNext) {
        soFar = insert (p, soFar);
    }
    return new IntList (soFar);
}


// values will be in decreasing order.
private DListNode insert (DListNode p, DListNode head) {
    DListNode q=new DListNode(p.myItem);
    if(head==null){
        head=q;
        return head;
    }
    if(q.myItem>=head.myItem){
        DListNode te=head;
        q.myNext=te;
        te.myPrev=q;
        q=head;
        return head;
    }
    DListNode a;
    boolean found=false;
    for(a=head; a!=null;){
        if(a.myItem<q.myItem){
            found=true;
            break;
        }
        else{
            a=a.myNext;
        }
}
    if(found==false){
        DListNode temp=myTail;
        temp.myNext=q;
        q.myPrev=temp;
        myTail=q;
        return head;
    }
    if(found==true){
    DListNode t;
    t=a.myPrev;
    a.myPrev=q;
    t.myNext=q;
    q.myPrev=t;
    q.myNext=a;
}
    return head;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit hard to read through but I noticed a few problems

**First**:
handling the case where you are inserting a number at the head of the list:

```
if(q.myItem>=head.myItem){
        DListNode te=head;
        q.myNext=te;
        te.myPrev=q;
        q=head;
        return head;
    }
```

specifically the line `q=head;` and the return. `q=head` can be removed, and it should return `q` not head because `q` is the new head. I think what you meant to do was `head=q; return head;`. The current code will essentially add the new node on the front but never return the updated head so they will "fall off the edge" in a way.

**Second**:
I am assuming `myTail` is some node reference you are keeping like `myHead` to the original list. I don't think you want to be using it like you are for the sorted list you are constructing. When you loop through looking for the place to insert in the new list, use that to determine the tail reference and use that instead.

```
DListNode lastCompared = null;
for(a=head; a!=null; a=a.myNext) {
    lastCompared = a;
    if(a.myItem<q.myItem) {
        break;
        }
    }
if( a )
    {
    // insert node before a
    ...
    }
else
    {
    // smallest value yet, throw on the end
    lastCompared.myNext = q;
    q.myPrev = lastCompared;
    return head;
    }
```

**Finally** make sure myPrev and myNext are being properly initialized to null in the constructor for DListNode.

*disclaimer* I didn't get a chance to test the code I added here, but hopefully it at least gets you thinking about the solution.

---

A couple stylistic notes (just a sidenote):

1. the repeated if->return format is not the cleanest in my opinion.
   I generally try and limit the exit points in functions
2. There are a lot of intermediate variables being used and the names are super
   ambiguous. At the very least try and use some more descriptive
   variable names.
3. comments are always a good idea. Just make sure they don't just explain what the code is doing - instead try and
   convey thought process and what is trying to be accomplished.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the bugs and now it works. Can you please elaborate why myTail was not working as I expected. I am still not sure about that. I deleted myTail and changed as you suggested.

Comment: I am assuming that `myTail` was initially pointing to the last node in the unsorted list. `temp` is created as pointing to `myTail`, and that is being used as the basis to insert `q`. What is really happening there is you are attaching `q` to the end of the unsorted (input) list, hence why that list would potentially keep growing and reevaluating nodes. I would suggest sketching out a list with some pointers to nodes to walk through it visually. If this response answered your question please 'Accept' it as the answer so the question is marked as answered.